# Should stop function be called after successful start function of `signalR.HubConnection`

Tags: angular, signalr

I have a client - server application.
After I successfully start the `SignalR` connection (on Angular client side), should I also `close` the connection in `ngOnDestroy` or the framework does it?
In all examples on internet that I have seen, there is no handling of a `close` connection.